# Javascript/html game using columns and rows

Tags: javascript, html

so I've been working on this for a few days now. This is what the game is supposed to do:

Using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery, or Angular code create a matrix 10 X 10 with columns/lanes using numbers and rows using letters to identify the cells. There will be two vehicles that randomly select a cell on the grid for placement. Randomly place ball target (the to acquire) somewhere on the grid. Have the vehicles check each column lane looking for the target. Once all cells have been checked in that lane have them move to another fresh lane that has not been checked. Keep a timer running to show time to acquire the target.

So far I was able to code the grid and the timer. So, what I need help doing, is placing a target/ball on the grid that is static, and then two finders/vehicles are then randomly placed on the grid.Going from left to right, they step through to the next column, until one of the cars is in the same column as the ball. There is a timer that sees how long it takes for one vehicle to land in same column as the ball.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Soccer Ball Game</title>
 <style>
 button {
 font-size:40px;
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 }

 .cars{
  background-color: green;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
  <body onload="createButtons(row, col)">
  <div id="buttonArea">
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="btnNewGame" onClick="findBall()" value="ResetButtons"/></input>
  <script>
  

   var col = 10;
   var row = 10;
   var dCheck = true;
   function createButtons(row,col){
    var counter = 1;
    var element = document.getElementById("buttonArea");

     for(countR = 1; countR <= row; countR++){

      for(countC = 1; countC <= col; countC++){
       var newButton = document.createElement("button");
       newButton.setAttribute("id", "btn" + counter);
       newButton.setAttribute("type", "button");

       newButton.setAttribute("class", "noclass");
       element.appendChild(newButton);
       counter++;
      }
      var breakLine = document.createElement("br");
      element.appendChild(breakLine);
     }

   }
   
   
 
   
   function resetButtons(){
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for(var i = 0; i < (buttons.length); i++){
     buttons[i].innerHTML = "";
     buttons[i].disabled = false;
     buttons[i].setAttribute("class", "noclass");
    }

   }


  </script>
  </body> 
</html>
```

And here is a timer code:

```html
let timer={};
timer.counter=0;
timer.start=()=&gt;{
 timer.ticker=setInterval(()=&gt;{ timer.counter++; },1000);
};
timer.stop=()=&gt;{
  clearInterval(timer.ticker);
};
let checker=(callback)={
 timer.start();
 //check each row in column
 //if hit timer.stop();
callback(timer.counter);
};
checker((count)=&gt;{
 console.log('it took '+count+' second to hit target');
});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Would you please update your post and make your question more clear?

Comment: I added a new paragraph hopefully explaining better what needs to be done

Comment: It looks like you have several questions lumped in here. 1) Placing items on the grid. 2) Iterating through the grid row by row.  I would suggest making separate questions for each one (and any others you have).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lots of ways that you can use to place a target/ball on the grid buttons, For example, you can use CSS class trick like this:

```
.ball{
 background: URL(ball.png);
}
```

And then add it to one of your buttons randomly. And for cars, you can use the same trick.
I hope this will help you a little bit but if you something else please correct me.